# How to switch a tmux session created by a script

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

I'm trying to run a script that automates opening a `tmux` session and then run some commands, like opening some windows and panes etc.

I tried to use `xdotool` then I thought it's better to use just tmux and call `send-keys`

```
#!/bin/bash

SESSIONNAME="Working"     # Set tmux session name
echo "Starting a tmux session"
sleep 2s

if (tmux has-session -t "$SESSIONNAME" 2> /dev/null); then
  echo "Session '$SESSIONNAME' exists."
else
  tmux -u new-session -d -s $SESSIONNAME
  tmux send-keys -t $SESSIONNAME "echo 'hello world'" ENTER
fi

#tmux a
#tmux send-keys -t $SESSIONNAME "echo 'hello'" ENTER
exit 0
```

The problem with this script the created session is not automatically attached and if I tried to call `tmux a` before running some `send-keys`, these commands don't run at all.

Please, can you clarify or guide me a bit on how to accomplish the goal?

Answer (score 0):

Attach the session at the end of your script with "tmux attach -t$SESSIONNAME" or "tmux switch-client -t$SESSIONNAME" if inside tmux. You can check for $TMUX so see if you are inside.

Comment: The session does attach, but it doesn't run the `send-keys`. I tried your suggestion in place of commented lines.